# Update method in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was trying to update values in my dictionary, I came across 2 ways to do so:

```
product.update(map(key, value))

product.update(key, value)
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The difference is that the second method *does not work*:

```
>>> {}.update(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

[`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) expects to find a iterable of key-value pairs, keyword arguments, or another dictionary:

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.
>
> `update()` accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs: `d.update(red=1, blue=2)`.

`map()` is a built-in method that produces a sequence by applying the elements of the second (and subsequent) arguments to the first argument, which must be a callable. Unless your `key` object is a callable and the `value` object is a sequence, your first method will fail too.

Demo of a working `map()` application:

```
>>> def key(v):
...     return (v, v)
... 
>>> value = range(3)
>>> map(key, value)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> product = {}
>>> product.update(map(key, value))
>>> product
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Here `map()` just produces key-value pairs, which satisfies the `dict.update()` expectations.

Answer (score 5):

- Python 3.9 and [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) introduces the `dict union`, for updating one `dict` from another `dict`.

  - *Dict union will return a new `dict` consisting of the left operand merged with the right operand, each of which must be a `dict` (or an instance of a `dict` subclass). If a key appears in both operands, the last-seen value (i.e. that from the right-hand operand) wins.*
- See [SO: How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987) for merging with the new augmented assignment version.

  - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228920/7758804).

```py
>>> d = {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}
>>> e = {'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}
>>> d | e
{'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}
>>> e | d
{'aardvark': 'Ethel', 'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}
```

- Additional [examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#examples) from the PEP.

### Motivation

The current ways to merge two dicts have several disadvantages:

[`dict.update`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#id13)

`d1.update(d2)` modifies `d1` in-place. `e = d1.copy()`; `e.update(d2)` is not an expression and needs a temporary variable.

[`{**d1, **d2}`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#id14)

Dict unpacking looks ugly and is not easily discoverable. Few people would be able to guess what it means the first time they see it, or think of it as the "obvious way" to merge two dicts.